# Eclipse setup for a java project

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

Have a java project with couple of main java classes in it. On server this program has to run using java 1.5 version.

Trying to setup the same in eclipse.

Project properties/Java compiler    ---- set to 1.5

Project properties/Java build path  ---- Added JRE library ---> J2SE-1.5

But, when running one of the main class in the project in eclipse getting error as

SEVERE: Java Runtime Environment (JRE) version 1.6 is not supported by this driver

what else do I need to do in eclipse to run the program using java 1.5??

Comment: Why do you need to run this on 1.5?  It reached End of Life 7 years ago!

Answer (score 0):

Go to Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler and choose the default compliance level as 1.5

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Project properties/Java compiler make sure that 'Enable project specific settings' is checked.
Also, I would double check the build path for duplicate JRE libraries